# Notation for uncorrelated random structure in mixed model

Tags: mixed-model, notation

I will use the `hsb` dataset inside `descriptr` in  R as a toy example. In my original dataset variables are different of course, but they could be described as follows using this dataset.

```
library(descriptr)

mod_hsb <- hsb
```

Now, I want to specify the following model:

```
samplemod <- lmer(math ~ ses*female + (1 | prog/schtyp)+ (ses*female || race), data = mod_hsb)
```

I believe the model should have 4 different indexes k, j and i, and also the elec one, I have special problems to notate the last uncorrelated random intercept and slopes, which is equivalent to `...+(1|race)+(0+ses*female|race)`.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: `hsb` is not data included with R, can you edit the code to include the data?

Comment: I am sorry @sjp but ```hsb``` actually is a dataset included in R, as you can see here in this [link](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/descriptr/html/hsb.html).

Comment: Well, no, it's included in the package `descriptr`, not included in base R

Comment: Now that I have the data, the code is not reproducing on my machine. I'd like to help, but could you update the code so that I can see the data you are working with? Alternatively, you can paste the output of calling `dput()` on your dataframe

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I will update the post right now. Thanks!